# Wrong result when realizing fixed-point biquad IIR filter

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response, c, fixed-point

I'm implementing a fixed-point direct form I biquad filter with Q1.15 precision. I use fraction saving to improve quantization error. However, my function gives me the different results compared by MATLAB's `filter`. I didn't find anything wrong, please help. My code is as follows

```
void iir_biquad_df1_16(
    const short* pCoeffs,             /* b0, b1, b2, a1, a2 */
    short* pStates,                   /* x[n-1], x[n-2], y[n-1], y[n-2], fraction_state */
    const short* pSrc,                /* Input buffer */
    short* pDst,                      /* Output buffer */
    unsigned int blockSize,           /* Frame length */
    const unsigned int postShift,     /* Post shift when coefficients out of range [-1,1) */
    const unsigned int nSections      /* Number of cascaded sections */
)
{
    short* pIn = pSrc;                              /* Source pointer */
    short* pOut = pDst;                             /* Destination pointer */
    short* pState = pStates;                        /* State pointer */
    const short* pCoeff = pCoeffs;                  /* Coefficient pointer */
    int acc;                                        /* Accumulator */
    int b0, b1, b2, a1, a2;                         /* Filter coefficients */
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;                             /* Filter state */
    int xIn;                                        /* Temporary input */
    unsigned int shift = 15U - postShift;           /* Post shift for output */
    unsigned int mask = (1 << shift) - 1;           /* Fraction saving */
    int saturation = (0x00008000 << shift) - 1;
    unsigned int samples, section = nSections;      /* Loop counters */
    
    do
    {
        /* Read the coefficients */
        b0 = (int)(*pCoeff++);
        b1 = (int)(*pCoeff++);
        b2 = (int)(*pCoeff++);
        a1 = (int)(*pCoeff++);
        a2 = (int)(*pCoeff++);
        
        /* Read the state values */
        x1 = (int)(*pState++);
        x2 = (int)(*pState++);
        y1 = (int)(*pState++);
        y2 = (int)(*pState++);
        acc = (int)(*pState);
        pState -= 4;
        
        samples = blockSize;
        
        while (samples > 0U)
        {
            xIn = (int)(*pIn++);
            /* acc =  b0*x[n] + b1*x[n-1] + b2*x[n-2] - a1*y[n-1] - a2*y[n-2] */
            acc += b0*xIn + b1*x1 + b2*x2 - a1*y1 - a2*y2;
            
            if (acc >  saturation) acc =  saturation;         /* saturate if necessary */
            if (acc < -saturation) acc = -saturation;
            
            x2 = x1;
            x1 = xIn;
            y2 = y1;
            y1 = acc >> shift;
            
            
            *pOut++ = (short)y1;
            acc &= mask;

            samples--;
        }

        /* Store the updated state variables back into the pState array */
        *pState++ = (short)x1;
        *pState++ = (short)x2;
        *pState++ = (short)y1;
        *pState++ = (short)y2;
        *pState++ = (short)acc;

        /* Subsequent sections take previous output buffer as input */
        pIn = pDst;
        pOut = pDst;
    
    } while (--section);
}
```

I have 100 samples for input signal, and two cascaded biquad IIR filters. The block size is 50 so I have 2 blocks to process in order. The main function for test is given by

```
int main()
{
    short x[100] = { 10313,13297,-12223,13546,4337,-13188,-7258,1536,14992,15233,-11219,15420,14980,-479,9840,-11735,-2564,13623,9575,15057,5103,-15214,11440,14221,5857,8446,7967,-3532,5095,-10775,6752,-15341,-7310,-14871,-13201,10599,6384,-5993,14753,-15255,-2007,-3881,8700,9673,-10261,-335,-1783,4794,6860,8346,-7339,5888,5082,-11056,-12485,-54,15065,-5230,2794,-9050,8234,-8025,195,6523,12809,15050,1547,-11842,-11492,-7946,11165,-8052,10298,-8404,14066,-4916,-9942,-8156,3803,-875,-4861,10841,2794,1629,13671,-7018,8428,8314,-3918,2222,-13898,-14616,1009,9148,14222,-12127,2255,-1003,-15994,-5337 };
    short y[100] = { 0 };
    short coeffs[5 * 2] = { 575, -1150, 575, -31232, 14931, 575, 1150, 575, -32621, 16238 };
    short states[5 * 2] = { 0 };
    unsigned int blockSize = 50;
    unsigned int postShift = 1;
    unsigned int nSections = 2;
    // the first block of 50 samples
    iir_biquad_df1_16(coeffs, states, x, y, blockSize, postShift, nSections);
    // the second block of 50 samples
    iir_biquad_df1_16(coeffs, states, x + blockSize, y + blockSize, blockSize, postShift, nSections);

    return 0;
}
```

The input signal is random noise generated in MATLAB and the filter coefficients is also designed in MATLAB. The MATLAB validation code is

```
% clear
%% filter design
fs = 48000;
f1 = 50;
f2 = 600;
w1 = f1 / (fs / 2);
w2 = f2 / (fs / 2);
N = 2;
[b_bp, a_bp] = butter(N, [w1, w2], 'bandpass');

%% convert to cascade biquad
[sos,g] = tf2sos(b_bp, a_bp);
b1 = sos(1,1:3) * sqrt(g); a1 = sos(1, 4:6);
b2 = sos(2,1:3) * sqrt(g); a2 = sos(2, 4:6);

postShift = 1;
b1_q14 = int16(b1*2^14);
b2_q14 = int16(b2*2^14);
a1_q14 = int16(a1*2^14);
a2_q14 = int16(a2*2^14);

%% input signal generation
rng(0)
x = rand(1, 100) - 0.5; % uniform distribution in range (-0.5, 0.5)
x_q15 = int16(x*2^15);
x = x';

%% output signal
y1 = filter(b1, a1, x);
y2 = filter(b2, a2, y1);
y1_q15 = int16(y1*2^15);
y2_q15 = int16(y2*2^15);
```

Since some of the filter coefficients are out of range of $[-1, 1)$, I impose a post shift that shrinks all filter coefficients in the range of $[-1, 1)$. Thus the conversion to fixed-point is multiplied by $2^{14}$ and gives a Q2.14 precision.

After debugging, I found that the output signal of the first biquad section seems to be correct, but after cascading the second section, the final output is not the same as MATLAB gives. This problem has bothered me for two days. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I plot the signal before and after the second section of biquad filter. The input signal is random noise

[image]

and the filtered signal after the first secion of filter is

[image]

We can see that the C output is nearly identical with the MATLAB output. However, after the second biquad, they are quite different.

[image]

Does it mean that 16-bit word length is not long enough for my application (audio processing)?

Comment: If the first block works fine, then the code probably works. Is your output on the same format as your input? It should be...

Comment: Does anything change if you increase the block size to 100 and just call `iir_biquad_df1_16` once?

Comment: @PeterK. No, I got the same result. The filter states are just two previous samples of input and output, I didn't find anything wrong with the states.

Comment: @Ben Yes, the output and the input are both `short` and have Q1.15 format.

Comment: i like that you're noise-shaping using fraction saving.  (where did you get that idea from? :-) ------ looking over your code now.

Comment: You realize that `y1` and `y2` of `section` is the same as `x1` and `x2` of `section-1`?  But it's probably more efficient to process blocks of samples for each section rather than process all of the sections for each sample in the block.

Comment: Instead of `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, `a1`, and `a2` being `short` and you casting them to `int` in the inner computation (which is repeated), why not declare those coef variables as `int` and cast them  when loading them from the coef array?

Comment: How is `b0` getting defined?  I don't see it in your MATLAB code.

Comment: But your C code looks correct.  Both the sample processing code `iir_biquad_df1_16()` and the `main()` look correct to me.  As far as I can tell, this code should work.  Dunno how you defined `b0` unless you are saying it's the same as `b2`.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Hi robert! Thank you for replying! Appreciate so many useful advice! The filter coefficient is defined by `b1 = sos(1,1:3) * sqrt(g); a1 = sos(1, 4:6);` This gives me `[b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2]` of the 1st section of biquad filter and we know that `a0 = 1` so it is discarded in the C code. `b1, a1, b2, a2` in MATLAB mean the numerator and denominator arrays of the first and the second biquad filters, not single values.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson and btw, fraction saving is learned from one of your answers : ) I've learned a lot on this site!

Comment: The difference *could* be due to coefficient quantization.  You have only 14 bits after the binary point.  I can tell that your cascaded sections is one HPF section `{575, -1150, 575, -31232, 14931}` followed by one LPF section '{575, 1150, 575, -32621, 16238}`.  But I would think that, given the same initial states, the two filters should follow each other more closely.  16-bit precision (for numbers ranging $-2 \le a_1 < 2$) should be plenty good for filters that are not overly resonant.  I dunno why the two realizations do not conform more to each other.

Comment: Do you know for sure that your `int`s are 32-bit and your `short`s are 16-bit?  Perhaps you should use `int32_t` and `int16_t`.

Comment: I think it's coefficient quantization.  Your input signal is $\pm$0.5 and your output signal is about $\frac{1}{30}$ of the size.  Why not scale the `b0`, `b1`, `b2` coefficients 20 times bigger before quantizing them to the nearest integer and see if you get better agreement between the MATLAB and C filtering?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thank you Robert! I've testified that my `int` is 32 bit and `short` is 16 bit. I'll have a try to scale up my coefficients and then quantize them. However, I need a bandpass filter which has a 0 dB gain over the pass band, so this is not an ultimate solution. I think the point is that the lower stop band frequency (50 Hz in my case) is too close to DC. Maybe I could downsample my input signal, band-pass filter, and then upsample, which is much more complicated and I dunno doing this way or just using 32-bit precision which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The C Implementation uses first biquad `states` for the second. Whereas the matlab implementation has initial states zero for both the biquads. Try using two separate state variables for each of the biquads.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for response! When I complete filtering and then store the filter states to the buffer, I use `*pState++`. So I don't think I'm using the first states for the second section. The `pState` array has a length of `5 * nSections`.

Comment: the `*pState++` variable that you are using is local to the biquad function - `iir_biquad_df1_16`. So the `states` variable in the calling function's value does not get changed. Request you to try printing the states pointer value before calling the biquad function call.

Thanks!

Comment: One more way to verify this is by adding a memset statement as below just before the second biquad call.
`memset(&states[0], 0, sizeof(states));`

This resets the `states` variable and is expected to make the C implementation in line with matlab.

Thanks!

Comment: // the `*pState++` variable that you are using is local to the biquad function - `iir_biquad_df1_16` //  that pState variable **is** local to the biquad function, but it is correctly inited to `pStates` value passed to it from main() which is the array `states`.

Comment: Found the mistake in my understanding. Apologies for the confusion and thanks for helping me understand @robertbristow-johnson